# Problema de Serializacion: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: serialización, casting

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el cual necesito retornar un objeto que serialice previamente pero me sigue dando error al momento de castear aun cuando mi ArrayList es de tipo Factura

```
   public void obtenerF() {

        try {
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(new 
            FileInputStream("Factura.obj"));
            facturas = (ArrayList<Factura>) entrada.readObject();
            entrada.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MnuPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: **A.** Al parecer en tu código la variable `facturas` está declarada como un `String` y luego quieres introducir un array en dicho `String` haciendo esto: `facturas = (ArrayList<Factura>) entrada.readObject();` Es lo que se puede **adivinar**, viendo el código y el mensaje de error, pues no indicas la parte donde creas la variable `facturas` . o bien **B**. Un paréntesis mal puesto: `facturas = ArrayList<Factura> (entrada.readObject());` o **C.** Tanto A, como B.

Answer (score 1):

Las excepciones de Java no te mienten. Si te dicen que recibiste un objeto tipo `String`, se envió un objeto tipo `String`. Tienes que revisar el código que produce la fuente que estas leyendo después.

Generalmente se recomienda de comprobar la clase de un objeto deserializado después de `readObject` con `if (objeto instanceof ...)`. Un *cast* sin comprobar casi nunca es una buena idéa.

Si controlas el código para serializas, prueba un `System.out.println(objeto.getClass().getName());` antes de guardar/enviarlo. Así te das cuenta donde nace el problema.